# Sockets :client won't connect with the server over WAN

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a chat program using java sockets between two mobile devices ,,when i try to connect the client to the server using the same network (LAN) it works fine and i am able to send from client to server and vice versa
but when i tried to connect them at (WAN) it didn't work 
Server Side ::

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread TH;
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket S;
    DataOutputStream DOS;
    String data;
    String recieved = "GPS";
    String Response="sondos";
    TextView et_port;
    TextView tv_receive;
    TextView tv_transmit;
    TextView status;
    boolean isbind = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et_port = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_port);
        tv_receive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_receive);
        tv_transmit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_transmit);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        Intent intent =new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
      establishconnection();
    }
   public void establishconnection()
 {
    TH=new

    Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {

            try {
                status.setText(MyService.getipaddress());
                ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
                while (true) {
                    S = ss.accept();
                    status.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        status.setText("connected");
                                    }
                                }
                    );
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(S);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    );
    TH.start();
}
    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
        private Socket ClientSocket;
        DataInputStream DIS;
        public CommunicationThread(Socket ClientSocket) throws IOException {
            this.ClientSocket = ClientSocket;
            DIS = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
            data = DIS.readUTF();
        }
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                data = data.toString();
                tv_receive.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        tv_receive.setText(data);
                    }

                });
                while (recieved.equals(data)) {
                    try {
                        DOS = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());
                        DOS.writeUTF(Response);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tv_transmit.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv_transmit.setText(Response);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        DOS.flush();
                        DOS.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            S.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
////    public static String getIpAddress() {
////        String ip = "";
////        try {
////            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
////                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
////            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
////                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
////                        .nextElement();
////                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
////                        .getInetAddresses();
////                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
////                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();
////
////                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
////                        ip += "Hosted On: "
////                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
////                    }
////                }
////            }
//        } catch (SocketException e) {
//            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        return ip;
//    }
```

Client Side::

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView  tv_device, tv_receive, tv_transmit;
    Button btn_connect, btn_GPS;
    EditText et_IP_Address, et_port, et_message;
    Socket S;
    DataOutputStream DOS;
    DataOutputStream DOS2;
    DataInputStream DIS;
    Thread TH;
    Thread TH2;
    String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et_IP_Address= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_IP_Address);
        et_port= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_port);
        et_message= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        et_message.setText("GPS");
        btn_connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        btn_GPS= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        tv_transmit=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_transmit);

        tv_receive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_receive);
        tv_device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_device);

        // connection
        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TH=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            S = new Socket(et_IP_Address.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(et_port.getText().toString()));
                            DOS = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });// End of thread
                TH.start();

            }
        }); // end of  buutton

        // Sending
        btn_GPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TH2=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                                DIS = new DataInputStream(S.getInputStream());
                                DOS2 = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());
                                DOS2.writeUTF(et_message.getText().toString());
                                tv_transmit.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        tv_transmit.setText(et_message.getText());
                                    }
                                });
                                try {
                                    DOS2.flush();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//                        CommunicationThread commThread = null;
//                        try {
//                            commThread = new CommunicationThread(S);
//                        } catch (IOException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
//                        new Thread(commThread).start();
//
                        try {
                            data = DIS.readUTF();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        data = data.toString();
                        tv_receive.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                tv_receive.setText(data);
                            }

                        });
                            try {
                                DOS2.close();
                                DIS.close();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                });  // end of thread

                TH2.start();


            }
        });    // end of button

    }
//    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable{
//        private Socket ClientSocket;
//        DataInputStream DIS;
//        public CommunicationThread(Socket ClientSocket) throws IOException {
//            this.ClientSocket = ClientSocket;
//        }
//        @Override
//        public void run() {
//            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
//                while(true){
//                    try {
//                    DIS = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
//                    data = DIS.readUTF();
//                } catch (IOException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
//                data = data.toString();
//                tv_receive.post(new Runnable() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        tv_receive.setText(data);
//                    }
//                });
//
//                }
//
//            }
//        }
//    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            S.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am using a service to keep the connection open

Comment: it is a tricky network setup. The server gateway may be dropping requests, or the client gateway may not be properly forwarding the requests. Try sniffing the packets

Comment: What's the observed effect when you run your application over a WAN? Any error?

Comment: You are creating a server socket in the device so that you can do a direct connection between 2 devices? If you are using WIFI, you need a proper port forwarding at router. If you using Mobile Data, AFAIK, most of the telco only allow outbound connect. It mean even you know your public ip on that time, unless telco help you forward port 8080 to your device, you will not able to connect to that device. Recommended using FCM or GCM instead.